# Is there a known problem with ContourPlot3D on MacOS Sierra?

Tags: plotting

I'm running macOS Sierra.  I can execute the ContourPlot3D command successfully.  However, whenever I use the mouse to manipulate the output – like rotating the graphic - my computer freezes and I have to do a force reboot of my laptop.  Is this a known problem?

I'm running Mathematica 11.0.0.0.

Comment: The [tag:bugs] tag should not be added to questions until your observations have been confirmed by other users.

Comment: Yes, it's a known problem.  Upgrade to 11.0.1.  You should always install bugfix releases, i.e. 11.0.x.

Comment: Several issues with certain GPUs on Mac have been fixed in 11.0.1, so trying that would be my first suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the information everyone.  I'll be upgrading.